# I have a question about mysql group matching score

Tags: mysql

The table below shows the results for sql.
The result values ​​for id '1' were grouped and outputted.

| id | class | name | counting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CLASS1 | A,B,C | 3 |
| 1 | CLASS2 | AA, BB | 2 |
| 1 | CLASS3 | AAA | 1 |

I want to calculate the match score using (in) condition.

```
SELECT SCORE FROM VIEW WHERE name IN ('A','BB','C')
```

If the above sql is executed.
If the counting is 3, if it matches the first name of each class, 3 points, the second is 2 points, and the last is 1 point.

If the counting is 2, I want to give 2 points if it matches the first name of each class, and 1 point for the second.

So, in the above result, A is 3 points in CLASS1, BB is 1 point in CLASS2, and C is 1 point in CLASS1, and the result is 5 points.

I thought as above, but it is too difficult to write a sql query.

give me a little tip.

thank you.

TEST SCHEMA *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8eac4c64561241a14d6c00e3dcd0b447)*

Comment: You should move away from storing CSV data like this in your tables.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() allows to define the value position in CSV value. Substracting it from total values amount (count the amount of CSV delimiters) gives the points. Then aggregate and calculate SUM(). But the best way is to rewrite your view and produce not CSV-compacted but separate rows with their enumeration over a group which is the points for definite value. PS. Avoid spaces between delimiter and value in CSV.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and corrections.I completed the calculations in a different way. However, I got help from the comments and the editors' corrections. thank you